# Next.js TypeError: result is not iterable at build

Tags: next.js, typeerror

Im facing this error with Next 13 App directory when I run npm run build, and It doesnt let me deploy successfully until I fix it, but I have no clue whats going on.
[image]
[image]

I have a /blog/[slug]/page.tsx where I fetch all the posts for the function generateStaticParams():
[image]

This is the function that gives me the error:
[image]

But for some reason, Im getting the error that says that posts is not iterable, and it actually is:
[image]

Does anyone knows what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. For some reason it was entering the catch when I ran npm run build, and I fixed it by deleting the headers in the axios call.